# Create an e-commerce that integrates other store

Tags: architecture, php, web-development, e-commerce

I would like to create an e-commerce website that integrate other e-commerce. I can retrieve their products using APIs or feeds. The problem is that all these information are different from shop to shop and I need something to uniform and show them in my e-store. I've tried to build a Woocommerce plugin but it lacks in performance because I have to retrieve thousands of products and every day check for some new in and update the inventory every 5 hours. What's the best architecture to use in my project? I think to rebuild my project using a PHP framework like Yii2. There is a faster and easier way to do it?

Comment: Since you're presumably doing this with the other web shop's permission, you could work together with them to develop a more efficient API that lets you access the listings and receive updates in real time.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way to solve this is through actual software architecture (I use clean architecture). A framework is not a real architecture. It may have suggestions for a pattern to work with it well or even enforce that pattern. This is not software architecture and doesn't solve very much outside of presenting your program.

You don't ask a presentation framework to solve data consistency problems. What you should do is try to protect it from data consistency problems. Frameworks are difficult, time-consuming, and constantly change. If you put this conversion code in it you are pouring gas on the fire. So you want to protect it by solving this outside of the way you present it. Have your answer first and then present it.

This means start with PHP, you can decide frameworks later. Create a use case (class GetAllProductsUseCase for example, up to you?). Create an interface Product -> getName(), getDesc() etc. That is the interface your application depends on and your implement it in a repository and it must complete this. Basically, you can create a model class where you conform to the interface for each API/feed and return the data you want in the repository so that it is already in the format you need.

I hope at least you get the main idea.